# Why won't anything show up in my JavaFX application?

Tags: java, object, layout, javafx

I am currently trying to make an 8x8 board and cannot seem to figure out why my rectangle objects are not showing. I am trying to figure out the logic behind one row before I do it multiple times to get the whole board. Below is my current code:

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Board extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    public void start(Stage ps) {

        TilePane tp = new TilePane();
        Pane p = new Pane();

        for (int column = 0; column > 8; column++) {
            // This loop is used to determine the center of the rectangle
            for (int x = 10; x < 160; x += 20) {        
                Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
                r.setWidth(20);
                r.setHeight(20);
                r.setX(x);
                r.setY(10);
                if (column == 0 || column % 2 == 0) {
                    r.setFill(Color.BLACK);
                }
                else {
                    r.setFill(Color.GREY);
                }
                tp.getChildren().add(r);
            }
        }

        p.getChildren().add(tp);
        Scene s = new Scene(p, 160, 160);

        ps.setScene(s);
        ps.setTitle("PP2 Halma Project");
        ps.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `for (int column = 0; column > 8; column++)` - This will never happen because 0 can never be more than 8.
2. `r.setX(x)` - I don't think you would need this. You should let `TilePane` layout the rectangles for you; you just need to define a size for it.
3. `Pane p = new Pane()` - Personally, I think this is redundant. Using just `TilePane` without it will work just fine. This will not cause your program to bug, though.